# get count row cypher neo4j

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

how  to  get  name of  the column returned  by  count  function

herer is the  problem

```
cypherquery='START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Ashish') MATCH n-[:f]-h RETURN h,count(h)'
```

first column name would  be  sure ' h '   which but  what  about  name of the  second column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the AS keyword, as follows:

```
'START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Ashish') MATCH n-[:f]-h RETURN h,count(h) as columnName'
```

Use the "columnName" to reference the result.